# Bag of visual words workflow after feature extraction: when to scale data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, k-means

I have already extracted image features of 3 classes using SURF (openCV) and stacked all descriptors together into a numpy array.

My next steps would be:

1. clustering using K-means
2. build feature histogram for each training case based on clusters
3. train a multi class linear SVM to separate cases based on feature histograms

My question is:
at what point would it be most appropriate to scale my data?

Should this be done before clustering, histograms or SVM?

I am using sklearn's [standard scaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html), as well as [linearSVC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html#sklearn.svm.LinearSVC).

Comment: This might help http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/

Comment: thanks for the great resource -- but are those operations done on the extracted features or on the pixels values?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383034/opencv-combining-surf-with-neural-network